# PHP: How to get age in php from day, month, year?

Tags: php, date

I have 3 variables $day, $month, $year each of them have the values what the users given to them.

I want to get his real Age too from these 3 variables.

For example the user enters this date for his birthdate in this format day,month,year:

> 04, 07, 1990 -> Now his age is 19

---

> 02, 07, 1990 -> Now his age is 20

I want to have it in this way.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Take a look at this related post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051011/how-to-calculate-year-from-entering-my-age-using-php/3051101#3051101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use something like this:

```
function age($bMonth,$bDay,$bYear) {
    list($cYear, $cMonth, $cDay) = explode("-", date("Y-m-d"));
    return ( ($cMonth >= $bMonth && $cDay >= $bDay) || ($cMonth > $bMonth) ) ? $cYear - $bYear : $cYear - $bYear - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`datediff`](http://www.addedbytes.com/code/php-datediff-function/) (custom) function. You need to subtract the birth date from current date.

Example:

```
echo 'Now his age is ' . datediff('yyyy', '9 July 1990', '3 June 2010', false);
```

Result:

```
Now his age is 19
```

Comment: There is no 'DateDiff' function...

You could instantiate DateTime twice (with the current date and birth date), and then call it's diff method.

My point being, that you weren't very helpful/specific...

Comment: @xil3: It is a custom function actually.

Comment: @xil3 You're right, there is no built-in function named `DateDiff`, that's why he linked to it.